# Flash AS3 & Base64 Library = comile errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors, base64

I have a problem using [Sociodox BASE64 LIBRARY library](http://sociodox.com/base64.html).
I’m totally newbie in Flash so please help.

I’ve connected the library with

```
import com.sociodox.utils.Base64;
```

After that I try to compile my project but get the following error:

> Base64.as, Line 146: 1100: Syntax error: XML does not have matching
>   begin and end tags. Base64.as, Line 146: 1084: Syntax error: expecting
>   rightbrace before end of program.

Here is a screenshot of the errors: [image: clip2net.com/s/5Jbzlt]

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code uses short Vector initialisation syntax: `new <int>[]` which your compiler tries to interpret as XML.
What are you using to compile? Flash or Flash Builder? I know that Flash Builder 4.7 should be able to handle this syntax, at least when you're compiling with an AIR SDK that contains the new ASC2 compiler.

Comment: I can confirm it works with the ASC1 compiler as well and I have used it in SWF-based projects, too.

Comment: Hi, I use Adobe Flash CS4, but I don't if it's Flash or Flash Builder. I assume I use default settings & compiler.

Comment: You could also just change the offending line into 
  `var decodeVars:Vector.<int> = Vector.<int>([]);`

Comment: After I changed the code as you described I have the following errors: http://clip2net.com/s/5JfPX3

Comment: Okay, the problem has been solved by changing project's properties from player 9.x to 10.x. Thanks!